# how to show error message on submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, webforms, angularjs-directive

Can you please tell me how to show an error message on submit button click ?.I am getting an error message after running the program (when I write required :true). I need to show an error message when a user submits the form. I am using this plugin https://github.com/McNull/angular-febworms

- Can we get onchange event of select field ?

In my example a red border is displayed when I run the application. I don't want this. I need this when a user clicks the 'submit' button

http://plnkr.co/edit/JOI82JrEBcKJMrzLgtZd?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@2.3.2" data-semver="2.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgithub.com/McNull/angular-febworms/master/package/febworms.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.0"></script>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgithub.com/McNull/angular-febworms/master/package/febworms.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dummy-schema.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyFormController as frmCtrl">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">

      <form class="form-horizontal" name="form.state" novalidate>



        <div febworms-form 
             febworms-schema="form.schema" 
             febworms-form-data="form.data">
        </div>




        <div class="form-actions">
          <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="form.state.$invalid" ng-click="frmCtrl.save()">Save changes</a>
        </div>



      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

But need to blur event to validate or onchange event ?

Comment: Should the error message be directly triggered by the click, or (which  seems more realistic to me) after an error response have come back from the server?

Comment: on button click..in other word.like my first field is requried true.when I run app it should not display red after run app when I click button(submit button) it show error the field is required.is this possible.or second example there is email type field it show that email is invalid when press submit button

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck any idea..?

Comment: The problem is, I know how I would proceed manually, but I don't know febworms. Have you declared some `name` attribute to your field?

Comment: I also know in static form .But I don't know how to validate at dynamic form.No don't use any attribute just study documenetation how to convert json to form using plugin.In that documentation not written how to validate form

Comment: I don't fully grasp your use case : the button can't be clicked anyway when the form is invalid. (?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59400/discussion-between-user944513-and-valentin-waeselynck).

Answer (score 0):

Since your form name is `'form.state'` and your field name is `'required'` (which is a bit confusing by the way, you may want to change that), you can get useful information about your validation state with the following expressions *in the scope of your form*:

```
form.state.required.$error // yields something like { "required": true, "pattern": false }
form.state.required.$valid // yields a boolean
form.state.$error
form.state.$valid
```

I haven't heard of a way of knowing whether a form has already been submitted or not. My best shot would be to add some state for this in the controller :

```
$scope.errorShown = false;
$scope.showErrorMessage = function(){
  $scope.errorShown = true;
};
```

And in your HTML :

```
    <div class="form-actions">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="form.state.$invalid" ng-click="(form.state.$valid ? frmCtrl.save() : showErrorMessage())">Save changes</a>
    </div>

    <div ng-if="errorShown && form.state.$invalid">
      Your form is not valid.
    </div>
```

Plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/n4N1s1XjL2YUh4EYTykH?p=preview).